# My "addChild" is not working Swift

Tags: swift

I have a really annoying error that when  I make an add child statement it says (as an error):
"Expected declaration" on the line of the addChild statement
i am using Xcode 6 with the latest version of swift

here is my code:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  Pocket Rocket
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 11/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lucas Farleigh. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit;

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"background")
    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playbutton")
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
        background.yScale = 2
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))            }
    self.addChild(background)

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)


        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you closed your `didMoveToView` method before that line:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))
    background.yScale = 2
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidX(self.frame))            
    self.addChild(background)
}
```

The error is because you can't have expressions at the class level.